# Tensorflow: How to create random input image masks using 'input data reader queues'?

Tags: tensorflow

I have some code to create random masks for input images in tensorflow.

```
mask = get_random_mask(...) # Returns some tensor in the shape of the input images
```

However a batch of input images is produced using

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
image_list, label_list , img_type = read_labeled_image_list(data_dir, data_list)
images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=tf.string)
queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels],shuffle=True)
image, label = read_images_from_disk(queue)
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size)
```

The thread to create input batch data is then started using

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)
```

However after a few iterations the program fails with this error:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
```

I'm quite sure that the error results from the fact, that the masks are not produced at the same pace as the input image and label batches. However I'm not sure how to tell Tensorflow to create masks at the same speed. Does anyone have an idea?

Do I have to create a list of random masks at the beginning of the same size as `image_list` ?

Answer (score 0):

Production rates won't cause an error like that; downstream queues would just block temporarily. This error seems to indicate that the training dataset was exhausted, and no instruction was given to read it again (or an explicit epoch limit was reached). Often a [string_input_producer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) with `num_epochs=None` (default) is used to loop through the dataset indefinitely.

Comment: `num_epochs=None` seems to be the default case already. I have a feeling that TF cannot call values from tensors which are not managed by `slice_input_producer` no matter if its a random mask or a constant one-loaded from disk (which I also tried).

Comment: Could you post a complete end-to-end reproduction of the issue? Hard to debug in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Actually the error message was quite misleading. It had nothing to do with any of `FIFOQueue` or `insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)`.
I ended up checking every tensor dimension during the preprocessing. I had some dimension mismatch when using the masks. Unfortunately the "empty queue" error was quite misleading. Sorry for the poor solution. Still thanks for your help @Allen Lavoie